# unable to show image on google map api v2 in android using groundOverlay

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have used used map api v2 in android. I'm able to load an image over the map using groundoverlay but the image is shown very small. I need to load the image completely over the mapview, e.g. covering the whole maps area. Can someone help me with this.. [Here is the image](http://www.trimble.com/positioning-services/interactive-map/interactive-map.aspx) i want to load over the map
Thankyou in advance...

```
public class GroundOverlayDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private static final int TRANSPARENCY_MAX = 100;
    private static final LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);
    //private static final LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(18.5236, 73.8478);

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GroundOverlay mGroundOverlay;
    private SeekBar mTransparencyBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ground_overlay_demo);

        mTransparencyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.transparencySeekBar);
        mTransparencyBar.setMax(TRANSPARENCY_MAX);
        mTransparencyBar.setProgress(0);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(NEWARK, 8));


        mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.omnistar_hp)).anchor(0, 1).position(NEWARK, 8600000f, 6500000f));
    //.position(NEWARK, 9999999.0f));//, 10000000f));

        mTransparencyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (mGroundOverlay != null) {
            mGroundOverlay.setTransparency((float) progress / (float) TRANSPARENCY_MAX);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had done it wid myself only and it works exactly the same i wanted and never crashes wid images..below is code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.util.TypedValue;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;





        public class MapDisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity implements         OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener  {
        private GoogleMap myMap;

        private static  LatLng SearchPlace;
        double Latitude;
        double Longitiude;
        List<Address> addresses;

        //Address location;
        BitmapDescriptor image;
    /// private static final LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(18.5236, 73.8478);


            private GroundOverlay mGroundOverlay;

            //this is for omnistarg dont touch this 
            LatLng southwest= new LatLng(-85.513398,-178.242187);

            LatLng northeast= new LatLng(85.513398,178.242187);

         float zoomValue = 7.0f;
        private String SpinerValue;
        private Bitmap bitmap;
            @Override
            `enter code here`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);
        //VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(4 * 1024 * 1024);
        Log.v("Utils", "Max mem in MB : " +    (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/(1024*1024)));
        Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        Debug.getNativeHeapSize();

        initActionBar();

        //textInfo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

           FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
           SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
            = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
           myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();





          // myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


          // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
           myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
          // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
           //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);


           myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
           myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
           myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
           myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

           Intent intent=getIntent();
           Latitude=intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0.000);
           Longitiude=intent.getDoubleExtra("Longititude", 0.000);
           SpinerValue=(String)intent.getStringExtra("SPINNERVALUE");

           SearchPlace = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitiude);

           myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SearchPlace));
           myMap.addMarker(new   MarkerOptions().position(SearchPlace));//.title(PlaceName));
           drawImageOverMap();

//         BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
//         opts.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
//         opts.inPurgeable=true;        
//         opts.inSampleSize=8;
//        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_g);

    }



    public void drawImageOverMap(){

           myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomValue));

                //image =BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.omnistar_g);
           if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("TEC")){
               //centerpoint_vrs
               bitmap =   (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        //.transparency(0.4f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));

           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniSTARG2")){
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_g_img);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.4f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniStarHP")){
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_hp_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.4f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
           /////////////////////////////////////////////
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniStarVBS")){
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_vbs_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.4f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));

           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("OmniSTARXP")){
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.omnistar_xp_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.4f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("RTXStandardviaCellular")){
              //rtxcell 
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rtx_cell_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.3f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("RTXFastviaSatellite")){
               //rtxfast.png
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rtx_fast_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.3f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("RTXStandardviaSatellite")){
               //rtxsat.png
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rtx_sat_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.3f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
           else if(SpinerValue.equalsIgnoreCase("VRSNow")){
               //vrsnowtec.png
               bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.vrsnow_tec_two);


                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 o2.inSampleSize=4;
                 image=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    LatLngBounds bounds =new LatLngBounds( southwest,  northeast);


                    mGroundOverlay  = myMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(image)
                        .transparency(0.3f)

                        //.anchor(0, 1)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds));
           }
                        // InputStream is =getClass().getResourceAsStream(omnistar_g);
                        //bitmap = readAssetsBitmap("omnistar_g.png");
                         //bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.trimble_screen_logo);
                         //bitmap=bitmap(is);


                         //image =BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.omnistar_g);


                                 bitmap.recycle();
                                 bitmap = null;
                                 System.gc();
                                 Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); 



    }
```

Comment: the only problem which i was facing was after loading large size images it was getting crash due to heap size exceeding bcoz of images..den i reduced images size and used it. also had done some things in code which you can refer above which help in avoiding crash app using images..Thanks to google docs it helped me lot and finally i made it..